# Sample application for access log sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to learn about access log sampler and how to use it. I am looking for sample application which can generate access logs on tomcat server. Can anyone help me with such an application

Answer (score 1):

As per [The JMeter Access Log Sampler - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-access-log-sampler-a-guide/)

> To get an access log from a web-server suitable for the standard parsers of the Access Log sampler, your web server should be configured to write logs in the [NCSA Common Log format](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#common). If your web server does not support this format, you can always try some of the numerous converter-applications, for example: [RConvlog](http://labs.rebex.net/RConvLog).

The most lightweight application you can use is [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/) itself